# archlinux internet connection problems

Tags: wifi, archlinux

ive been struggling for two days now trying to get an internet connection on arch linux so i can install but im not having any luck. The macbook pro im installing on doesnt have ethernet hook plus i just checked my comcast router and its not ethernet anyway. I had a usb internet dongle i use for my raspberry pi2 i put that in i can scan and get networks i just cant connect to my home network. It has wpa password encryption and i dont control it my landlord does so i cant even turn it off. does anyone have any ideas on what i can do to get a connection or to get this thing to work. I almost get it to connect when i use wpa_supplicant but it will keep saying can connect. Thank you in advance for any help givin. Also i have honestly been on the arch linux wiki for two days hacking away with no luck. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use netctl's wifi-menu to connect to a wireless network?

```
wifi-menu <insert your wireless network interface name here>
```

for example if your wireless interface were "w1p3s0", you would write:

```
wifi-menu w1p3s0
```

To look up your wireless interface name:

```
ifconfig -a
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what my problem was every time i would start up arch i would start screwing with a bunch of different daemons and i think they were interfering with one another so i just went in this time and hopped on wpa_supplicant and enter all the info i needed then ran dhcpc and BAM! Im on in business thank you for your help.